# Checking Azure connected Database onClick for login

Tags: java, azure, android-studio, azure-mobile-services

So Azure spit the following code for me to insert into an activity (Android Studio is what I'm using)

Add the following line to the top of the .java file containing your launcher activity:

```
import com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.*;
```

Inside your activity, add a private variable

```
private MobileServiceClient mClient;
```

Add the following code the onCreate method of the activity:

```
mClient = new MobileServiceClient("https://pbbingo.azurewebsites.net", this);
```

Add a sample item class to your project::

```
public class ToDoItem{ public String id; public String Text;}
```

In the same activity where you defined mClient, add the following code:

```
ToDoItem item = new ToDoItem();
item.Text = "Don't text and drive";
mClient.getTable(ToDoItem.class).insert(item, new TableOperationCallback<item>(){
public void onCompleted(ToDoItem entity, Exception exception, ServiceFilter response)
{
if(exception == null){
//Insert Succeeded
} else {
//Insert Failed 
}
}});
```

My goal is to create a login page. I understand that the above was probably offered up more with a ToList in mind. I just want to get the syntax correct today. The problem I think, is my basic class structure. I have created an OnClick Listener within my on create that gets the ID from a button in my layout. I don't need it checking for anything in the database until the button has been actually clicked to either login or register.

```
public class LoginClass extends AppCompatActivity{  
       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          setContentView(R.layout.MyLoginLayout);
          MobileServiceClient mClient = null; 

          try {
              mClient = new MobileServiceClient ("myAzureWebsite", "AzureKey", this);
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}

Button Attempt = (Button) findViewById (R.id.mySubmitButton);
final MobileServiceClient finalMClient = mClient; // finalized so I can use it later. 

Attempt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick (View v) {
         final View thisView = v;
         final MyToDoItemClass item = new MyToDoItemClass();

In MyToDoItemClass I have two variables (Both String) Just left over from
the example of a ToDoList (they are String ID and String Text)

         item.Text = "Filler"; 
         item.ID = "Fill";
finalMClient.getTable(MyToDoItemClass.class).insert(new Table OperationCallback<item>() { //<--- I'm getting an error that the variable, item
is from an unknown class...

public void onCompleted (Item entity, Exception exception, ServiceFilterResponse response){
if(exception == null) {
Intent i = new Intent (LoginClass.this, MainActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
}else{
Toast.makeText(thisView.getContext(), "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}}
});
}
});
}}
```

The problem is with that the TableOperationCallback is saying that the item from MyToDoItemClass class is from an unknown class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many issues in your code, as below.

1. According to the javadoc for class [`MobileServiceClient`](https://azure.github.io/azure-mobile-apps-android-client/com/microsoft/windowsazure/mobileservices/MobileServiceClient.html), there is not a method `insert(TableOperationCallback<E> callback)`, so the code `finalMClient.getTable(MyToDoItemClass.class).insert(new Table OperationCallback<item>() {...}` is invalid.
2. The generics `E` in `Table OperationCallback<E>` means that you need to write a POJO class name instead of `E`, not an object variable name like `item`, so the correct code should be `new Table OperationCallback<MyToDoItemClass>`, please see [the Oracle tutorial for Generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/) to know more details.
3. The figure below shows all methods `insert` of class `MobileServiceClient`. The bold word `Deprecated` under the method name means that you should not use it for developing on new project, it‘s only compatible for old project on the new version of Java SDK.

[image]

Please follow the offical [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-android-how-to-use-client-library) to develop your app. Any concern, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: Appreciate it so much. I assumed the methods provided we're self sufficient (As long as the imports and proper lib folders were included) but I'll put it together correctly now.